# Make part of a paragraph editable

Tags: html, contenteditable

I am making an interactive poem where I have blank spaces that can be filled in with the right word. Can anyone advise me on how to make just these spaces editable and not the rest of the poem?

Here is the poem:

```
<pre id="poem">
<b><u>Social Media</b></u>

Relax yourself,
As I ______
through your mind
Scroll down the pages
of your spine
Reading every word 
and thought on
your ____ like a ____
Stumbled Upon 
you then _______ onto
your looks--IGuess
I'm ______ into you
You're my one
and only ________

Will you ______ me?

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround the editable areas with a `<span>` element which is `contenteditable`:

```js
function isValid()
{
  if (document.getElementById('poem-word1').innerText == 'test') {
    alert("valid");
  } else {
    alert("not valid");
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="poem">
<b><u>Social Media</b></u>
Relax yourself,
As I <span contenteditable id="poem-word1">______</span>
through your mind
Scroll down the pages
of your spine
Reading every word 
and thought on
your <span contenteditable>____</span> like a <span contenteditable>____</span>
Stumbled Upon 
you then <span contenteditable>_______</span> onto
your looks--IGuess
I'm <span contenteditable>______</span> into you
You're my one
and only <span contenteditable>________</span>

Will you <span contenteditable>______</span> me?
</pre>
<button onclick="isValid()">Validate</button>
```

**Note:** If you need to submit these values you should use a `<form>` with `<input>` elements.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I am going to have to create some javascript to check if the value entered is correct. Is the only way to do that by creating input elements?

Comment: No this is also possible with `<span>` elements (but everyone can see the solution in javascript sourcecode ;)).

Comment: its for a college assignment so thats absolutely fine haha thanks a million for your help

Comment: I have just tried using span to check if it is correct but that doesnt work. How would i go about it?

Comment: added logic for the first word. I recommend to use jQuery to solve this.